# Resolve query containing multi columns and subquery return more than 1 value

Tags: sql-server

I have a very simple table with value:

```
CREATE TABLE multiplication(
        a SMALLINT, b SMALLINT);
INSERT INTO multiplication(a, b)
VALUES (1, 2), (2, 4), (3, 3)
```

When I'm trying to print Result by

```
DECLARE @Result INT;
SELECT @Result = (SELECT a, b, a * b AS c FROM multiplication)
PRINT @Result
```

I got the error

> Only one expression can be specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with EXISTS.

I know I get this error because I'm trying to assign two columns to one variable. Then I'm remove other columns and get the error

> Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I also try with select top but no luck. So how can get result where query containing multi columns and subquery return more than 1 value?

Comment: You cannot assign a resultset (which is what your SELECT statement returns) to a scalar value (your local variable). Think about your goal and what you are trying to accomplish. As it stands, you cannot execute this assignment / print logic.

Comment: What do you expect the _single value_ of `@Result` to be given this code? You're not just trying to assign three values (`a`, `b`, and `a * b`) you're also trying to assign those values _three times_ (once for each row in the table).

Comment: How to you expect to fit 3 columns, 3 rows SELECT into a scalar variable @Result???

Comment: "So how can get result where query containing multi columns and subquery return more than 1 value?".  You create a table variable instead of scalar variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you just trying to see your results?  Then just select the values without putting it into a variable:

```
SELECT a, b, a * b AS c FROM multiplication
```

If you really want it into a variable, then Sql Server has special variable types called [table variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/declare-local-variable-transact-sql).  Declare one like this:

```
declare @Results table (
    a smallint,
    b smallint,
    c smallint
);
```

Then insert into it like you would any other type of table:

```
insert @Results
SELECT a, b, a * b AS c FROM multiplication
```